# How to solve this linear matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How should I solve the following matrix equation? What is the solution for $X$?

$$B X C + B^T X C^T = D$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite it as a system of linear equations $(C^T\otimes B+C\otimes B^T)\operatorname{vec}(X)=\operatorname{vec}(D)$ (see Wikipedia entries on [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and [vectorisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) for the meanings of the symbols $\otimes$ and $\operatorname{vec}$) and solve it.

Comment: Nice observation, +1.